# Positive and negative voltage regulation

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

I need to get three voltage rails, +18 V, 0 V, -18 V and am trying to use a cheap XL6009 voltage boost module to do so.

My plan is to connect a 12 V line to two modules. This will give me +18 V and 0 V.

I was then planning to connect it as follows:

**Module 1:**

- +18 V output to +18 V load
- 0 V output to 0 V load

**Module 2:**

- +18 V output to the same 0 V load as module 1
- 0 V output to -18 V load

[image]

I am not sure if this will work or if it will damage anything.

This is the type of module I am using.

[image: XL6009 Module]

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing if the module can both *source* and *sink* current (for which we would need a datasheet with the internal architecture shown).

Comment: But possible for me, I have used these modules. Their - input and - output are shorted. What OP needs are **fully isolated** converters, these are not isolated at all.

Answer (score 6):

This will not work, you will be shorting the output of the top converter module.

I have drawn the short circuit with the orange trace:

[image]

The - input and the - output of these modules are **connected** so you cannot re-reference the outputs like you are doing.

What you need are converters with an **isolated output** or a module that will directly output -18 V / 0 / + 18 V. Have a look [here](https://www.cui.com/catalog/dc-dc-converters/isolated).

Comment: Perfect, very useful information thank you.

Am I able to use additional diodes to stop the short circuit?

Comment: No, diodes cannot help here. It is a **fundamental** limitation of this type of converter. I added a link (at the end of my answer) with modules that can provide -18 V, 0 V / + 18V. They are low power though, they cannot provide much current. If you need a more powerful supply you will need a supply that can deliver the -1 8 V / 0 V / + 18 V directly.

Comment: Ok, thinking in a different way, could I put power into one of the modules with the voltage reversed? I guess the capacitors would need to be reversed but would what work?

Comment: No no and no, there is no way around the issue. Stop suggesting things if you don't fully understand the real problem. *could I put power into one of the modules with the voltage reversed?* Sure, but that will mean **instant death** for the module. The capacitors will not have time to blow up. The XL6009 will blow first. **NEVER** reverse power on circuits unless they're designed for that.

Comment: Ok thank you.

I have been reading about inverter circuits to try and get a negative voltage however I am having little luck. 

There is a lot of information regarding using Buck-Boost converters to invert the polarity but I think that might be out of my capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf

has almost exactly what you require adjusting R2/R1:

[image: Inverting Converter XL6009]

Answer (score -3):

It is very simple- connect a Diode SS14 with its Cathode at Pin no. 3 of XL6009 and Anode to -ve terminal of a 100 mfd capacitor and +ve terminal of this capacitor to ground. The negative terminal of this extra capacitor will serve as -ve polarity supply. All this can be done with just a single XL6009 Module.